# On two dimensional fundamental theorem of calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f$ is a real-valued continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ in $[a,b]$ then

$\int_a^b f(t)\, dt = F(b)-F(a).$ When we know the function $F$, we can use this to find $f$ by taking derivative of $F$, that is, $f(x)=F^{'}(x).$ Generalizing this concept, now suppose I am interested in finding two  continuous real valued functions $f,g$ defined over $[a,b]^2$ such that

$$\int\limits_{a}^b\int\limits_{a}^bf(x,t_1)g(y,t_2)dxdy=F(t_1,t_2).$$ Is there a method to know when can we construct such $f,g$ and if yes, how do we do it. I do not know how to invoke fundamental theorem of calculus here.

Comment: You might want to know about **conservative vector fields**.